# Problem exporting polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, export

I am exporting data from a shapefile that has multiple polygons selected. When exporting all the attribute information is exported, but the polygon info is not and only one polygon is exported that then contains all the attribute information.

I am right clicking the selected shapefile and exporting the data, as I have done with most other selections.

What am I doing incorrectly and how do I solve?

Comment: Maybe you think you have multiple polygons selected but really you just have one multi-part polygon selected?  After making the selection check the attribute table and see how many rows are highlighted and confirm your selection.